# Spring MVC reusable view components

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jspinclude

I want to create an Spring MVC application, but I all tutorials and examples that I saw, there are one view for one controller action. But, can I make something like template.jsp with content and view components, with it's own minilogic and include in view tamplate.

Example template.jsp:

```jsp
<html>
  <head>
  ......
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="menu">
      #menuComponent
    </div>
    <content>
      #content from action
    </content>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Spring understands the importance of creating components as separate module. To do efficient layout Spring has Tiles. You can take a tutorial over [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-tiles-plugin-tutorial-example-eclipse/)

Comment: Does Tiles can pass parametrs to import views. For example in play, I can import it with params @header(message).

Comment: Not exactly, but in tiles you can create multiple templates i.e. a generic definition of header, footer, menu, content etc. And you can load each component properties dynamically